# Are metallic dragons' multiple breath weapons recharged separately or together?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons

Some dragons have multiple breath weapons, such as a bronze dragon having both a lightning breath and a repulsion breath. Do both of these breath weapons use the same recharge die? Do you need to roll multiple times for each breath weapon? Are both breath weapons expended once one is used?

This is probably in the manual somewhere but I don't have time to look it up and don't have manual with me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Do both of these breaths use the same recharge die? - Yes

> Breath Weapons (Recharge 5-6): The dragon uses one of the following
> breath Weapons...

Notice how both breath weapons are under the same entry with only one recharge listed. When monsters have attacks or abilities that are separate, they are listed separately. In this case, the dragon's breath weapons are considered one ability with two options. But the ability itself much recharge before it can be used again.

## Do you need to roll multiple times for each breath? - No

You only roll one recharge die for the breath weapon ability no matter which breath you use.

## Are both breaths expended once one is used? -Kind of

When you use the breath weapon ability you must choose one of the breaths to use. The other isn't expended but you must wait for the ability to recharge before you can choose either again.

Comment: "When monsters have attacks or abilities that are separate, they are listed separately." — I don't see any examples of that in the Monster Manual. Can you cite some? … "you must wait for the ability to recharge before you can choose either again." — I don't think that's clear; using a single sentence to classify the breath weapons could simply mean that they are the same kind of weapon and have the same chance of recharge, but still recharge independently. Also, I'm not sure why a creature releasing its acid reserve would also deplete its gas reserve. Official clarification would be helpful.

Comment: (To be clear, by examples, I mean a creature with multiple recharge abilities each listed separately.)